# Method 'addPostFrameCallback' cannot be called on 'SchedulerBinding?' because it is potentially null

Tags: flutter, dart, pubspec

I want to use syncfusion_flutter_charts in my project, but its gives me this error "cannot be called on 'SchedulerBinding?' because it is potentially null" on this dependency. how can i fix it.
I am using Flutter version 2.10.1 and syncfusion_flutter_charts: ^20.1.47+1

Launching lib\main.dart on SM G935F in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_core-20.1.60/lib/src/legend/legend.dart:548:39: Error: Method 'addPostFrameCallback' cannot be called on 'SchedulerBinding?' because it is potentially null.

- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
  Try calling using ?. instead.
  SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1102
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: Can you include your flutter version and `syncfusion_flutter_charts` version?

Comment: If your flutter is 3.0 or above all SchedulerBinding.instance! like this or any WidgetBinding.intance! is already remove the exclamatory from new version please check the package if its also follow the new update it might be those problem

Comment: I got the error, May this will help you. I follow the each given path in the error, like "/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_core-20.1.60/lib/src/legend/"  and Changes "SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback( ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^" to         "SchedulerBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback( ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ " And "SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback( () => Refresh();)" to SchedulerBinding.instance.?addPostFrameCallback( () => Refresh();)" in different files Like "Legend.dart", "chart_base.dart","circular_base.dart","funnel_base.dart",